# Difference between these two window structure?

Tags: python, gtk

Both of the code-snips below will create an empty Gtk window using python. However they seem quite different.

What is the main benefits of one vs the other ? 
Is there any performance, security or compatibility implications of choosing one versus the other?

1st code-snip:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from gi.repository import Gtk

win = Gtk.Window()
win.connect("delete-event", Gtk.main_quit)
win.show_all() 
Gtk.main()
```

2nd code-snip:

```
from gi.repository import Gtk, GdkPixbuf, Gdk
import os, sys

class GUI:
    def __init__(self):
        window = Gtk.Window()
        window.set_title ("Hello World")
        window.connect_after('destroy', self.destroy)

        window.show_all()

    def destroy(self, window):
        Gtk.main_quit()

def main():
    app = GUI()
    Gtk.main()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    sys.exit(main())
```

Ref1: [1st snip-code reference](http://python-gtk-3-tutorial.readthedocs.org/en/latest/introduction.html)

Ref2: [2nd snip-code reference](https://developer.gnome.org/gnome-devel-demos/stable/image-viewer.py.html.en)

Comment: For bigger programs the first approach won't really work. There is also a third way. You could also make a subclass of Gtk.Window.

Comment: Oh, I see for bigger programs the first approach would be much like old structured programs with all in one file or at least most of it in one file..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second snippet is more object-oriented, it defines a class `GUI` that you can extend for your application, which is a more elegant solution in my opinion. Additionally, it properly defines a `main()` function and calls it, this gives you more flexibility and allows you to import this module from elsewhere without instantiating the GUI on import. There are, as you asked, no real performance, compatibility or security implications.

In the 2nd snippet, I would, however, bind the `window` to `self` (`self.window = Gtk.Window()`), allowing you access from any method in the class.

Comment: Got it! so it really is a question of  structured versus object oriented approach? Makes sense! Thanks :)